# Hi. I am trying to make a responsive html page using 'float: left' with full page looks like 3 columns. The columns are not responsive

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, responsive

As the page width is changed ,using chrome browser, the 3 columns only narrow in width. The effect I am after is as the page narrows the 3 columns on a pc,become 2 columns on a ipad, and to 1 column for a mobile phone.

MY CODE:

```
<!-- PAGE STYLE -->         
<style>
    body {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 15%;
        padding-right: 15%;
        color:black;
        }
    h3  {padding-left;10px;}
    
    h2  {
         text-align:center;
        }
    p   {
        text-align:left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        }
    span {float:left;
        width: 33.33%;
        background: #FF6347;
            }   
    
            <!-- STACKING COLUMNS CODE -->
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

<!-- Create three equal columns that floats next to each other -->
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; <!-- Should be removed. Only for demonstration -->
}

<!-- Clear floats after the columns -->
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

<!-- Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of 
next to each other -->
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column 
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
      }
}       
    
    </style>

</head>

<!-- ---------------------BODY ------------------------->

<body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
    
    <span class="span"><h3>Accounts payable</h3><p width="33%">Processing supplier 
    invoices and setting up payment batches.</p></span>
```

I have included the some CSS as this could be a conflict. It refers to 'max-width' as well. For the navigation bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
    <!-- NAVIGATION STYLE -->
    {
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: black;
    }

    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 10px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: grey;
      color: white;
    }

    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
```

I have searched widely for the answer but I am not a expert. Any help greatfully appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you change the percent of width of elements according to window width. Added some mini hacks to make it work as it should in the example below: (check it on full page for 3 column layout)

```css
.column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .column {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 996px) {
  .column {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
before floats
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">column A</div>
  <div class="column">column B</div>
  <div class="column">column C</div>
  <div class="column">column D</div>
  <div class="column">column E</div>
</div>
after floats
```